# sorting large vectors using user defined function in c/c++

Tags: c++, c

I wrote the following code for sorting two vectors according to my sorting criteria:

```
typedef pair<unsigned, pair<vector<unsigned>, vector<unsigned> > > Elem;
bool bucketComparator(const Elem& a, const Elem& b) {
    //find the min and max of "a" and "b"
    // return true if a should go before b in the sort
    unsigned minA,maxA;
    unsigned minB,maxB;
    if((a.second.first).size()<=1){
        minA=maxA=*((a.second.first).begin());
    } else{
        minA=*std::min_element((a.second.first).begin(),(a.second.first).end());
        maxA=*std::max_element((a.second.first).begin(),(a.second.first).end());
    }
    if((b.second.first).size()<=1){
        minB=maxB=*((b.second.first).begin());
    } else{
        minB=*std::min_element((b.second.first).begin(),(b.second.first).end());
        maxB=*std::max_element((b.second.first).begin(),(b.second.first).end());
    }
    if((minA<=minB)&&(maxA<=maxB)){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
main()
{
   vector<Elem> A;
   //initializing vector A with values
   std::sort(A.begin(), A.end(), bucketComparator);
   //further computation using vector A
}
```

Error: Segmentation fault for large data.

I find that I am getting segmentation fault when size of vector A is 223080 or greater. But when the size of vector A is less than 100 then the code works well. I am unable to understand the reason for this as the I am running the code on 64GB RAM. Can some one please help me with this a bit.

Also when I run top command on linux I find that the program does not even consume 0.1% (of 64GB) available RAM before stopping because of segmentation fault.

I even tried to find max and min by first sorting the vectors using std::sort and bubble sort -- but I am still getting the same error.

I am running the following version of gcc: gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3

Is there some way in which I can write my program such that it sorts large vectors according to the sorting criteria which I have used in:bucketComparator. I am fine with both c and c++.

Additionally, the code does not give segmentation fault when I do a simple std:: sort:

```
std::sort(A.begin(), A.end());
```

Comment: 64 GB RAM, are you sure, can you verify doing a right click on your `my computer` and then seeing the value in `Installed memory (RAM)` section?

Comment: @code frenzy Yes it am using a linux machine and I have 64 GB RAM. I even tried running the program on 400+ GB RAM server but still I am getting the same fault. I am unable to understand the reason for this behaviour of the program

Comment: where are you declaring and populating `subBucketPred`? you sure its the comparator raising the segfault?

Comment: @TZHX That's a large file..but you can get the error using some random values.

Comment: @TZHX I verified using simple std::sort the code does not give errors

Comment: What is vector A used for, typo?

Comment: What are you compiling your application as? 64 bit or 32 bit? The amount of RAM won't help you if you only have access to 2-4GB of it.

Comment: Is it possible that `(a.second.first).size()` (or b) could be 0, so you're dereferncing the `begin()` on an empty vector while I think is bad)

Comment: You do not provide *strict weak ordering*. If `minA = minB` and `maxA = maxB`, then both `bucketComparator( a, b )` and `bucketComparator( b, a )` return `true` which is not allowed. See [here](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) for more information.

Comment: You still have not posted compilable code, nor have you shown what `A` has to do with `subBucketPred`...

Comment: @ChristianHackl Sorry. I have edited the question..very sorry for the typo

Comment: @clcto Ok..thanks a lot...but i am not getting how should I do that..can u please explain that a little

Comment: @StegVerner changing `minA <= minB ...` to `minA < minB ...`, or maybe keeping `minA<=minB` but changing the second part to `maxA<maxB`. Just make sure it follows the rules described in the link I provided above.

Comment: @clcto Thanks it worked. But I also want my code to work for equality ..is there some way by which I may ensure that

Comment: @StegVerner what do you mean? You are sorting them, one will have to come before the other. If for two values `a` and `b`, both `f(a,b)` and `f(b,a)` return `false`, they are considered equivalent and the order is not guaranteed between them. You can use `std::stable_sort` if you want them to be in the same order as they were originally.

Comment: @StegVerner - check for equality. It won't matter in the case of std::sort, since it's not "stable", equal elements may get reordered. If you want to preserve the order of equal elements, use std::stable_sort(). In case of std::stable_sort(), the parameters to the compare function are compare(later element, earlier element), so a reordering only occurs if the later element is < earlier element (the order is kept if earlier element <= later element). Both sorts expect the compare function to be < not  <=. In a debug build, Microsoft's STL checks for this and throws an error if it's <=.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`std::sort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) describes the comparator properties:

> Binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments, and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned indicates whether the element passed as first argument is considered to go before the second in the specific ***strict weak ordering*** it defines.
>
> The function shall not modify any of its arguments.
>
> This can either be a function pointer or a function object.

Strict weak ordering is defined by the following traits ([source](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html)):

```
Irreflexivity                   f(x, x) must be false.
Antisymmetry                    f(x, y) implies !f(y, x)
Transitivity                    f(x, y) and f(y, z) imply f(x, z).
Transitivity of equivalence     Equivalence (as defined above) is transitive: if x is equivalent to y and y is equivalent to z, then x is equivalent to z.
```

Where two elements, `x` and `y`, are considered equivalent if both `f(x,y)` and `f(y,x)` are false.

The function you define does not follow these rules, specifically it violates irreflexivity and antisymmetry; when `minA == minB && maxA == maxB`, `bucketComparator(a,b)` and `bucketComparator(b,a)` both result in a `true` value. Since the functor is invalid, it results in undefined behavior.

You need to update your functor to provide strict weak ordering. One solution may be to change the statement:

```
if((minA<=minB)&&(maxA<=maxB))
```

to

```
if( minA <= minB && maxA < maxB )
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can see that *might* be wrong is that you are dereferencing what is returned by `std::min_element` and `std::max_element`, without checking to see if what they return are `<vector>.end()`, which is possible. Seg faults almost always happen when a pointer somewhere is dereferenced when it wasn't supposed to be dereferenced.

For example, if the vector is empty, `std::min_element` and `std::max_element` will return `<vector>.end()`, which you're dereferencing.

Answer (score 1):

if vectors `a.second.first` or `b.second.first` are empty then program will crash on dereferencing iterator taken from `begin()` call.

```
bool bucketComparator(const Elem& a, const Elem& b) {
    //find the min and max of "a" and "b"
    // return true if a should go before b in the sort
    unsigned minA,maxA;
    unsigned minB,maxB;

    const vector<unsigned> &vecA = a.second.first;
    const vector<unsigned> &vecB = b.second.first;

    //check if vectors empty
    if (vecA.empty()){
        return true;
    }
    if (vecB.empty()){
        return false;
    }

    if((vecA).size()==1){
        minA=maxA=*((vecA).begin());
    } else{
        minA=*std::min_element((vecA).begin(),(vecA).end());
        maxA=*std::max_element((vecA).begin(),(vecA).end());
    }
    if((vecB).size()==1){
        minB=maxB=*((vecB).begin());
    } else{
        minB=*std::min_element((vecB).begin(),(vecB).end());
        maxB=*std::max_element((vecB).begin(),(vecB).end());
    }
    if((minA<=minB)&&(maxA<=maxB)){
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

I also recommend to use local const reference variables to improve code readability and performance.

Comment: this will return true if both are empty, thus not providing strict weak ordering